# what is pcap magic number 0xc3d4a1b2?

Tags: pcap

I'm trying to write a program to read a pcap file captured in linux (tcpdump version 4.5.1 libpcap version 1.5.3) but I can't get the byte swapping correct.  The magic number isn't one of the values I expect (0xa1b2c3d4 or 0xd4c3b2a1) but is 0xc3d4a1b2.  the 'file' command correctly identifies it (tcpdump capture file (little-endian) - version 2.4 (Ethernet, capture length 65535)) and 'tcpdump -r' reads it but I don't understand how.  The magic number doesn't look little-endian OR big-endian to me.  The hexdump looks like:

```
0000000 c3d4 a1b2 0002 0004 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000010 ffff 0000 0001 0000 6be0 5a87 a747 0008
```

What byte ordering is this file in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably just how the data are displayed. I'm assuming your are using `hexdump`. By default this program is using a two-byte hexadecimal display, i.e. it is reading two bytes and interprets these as an unsigned short:

```
 $ hexdump file.pcap
 0000000 c3d4 a1b2 ...
```

To get a byte-wise display you can use for example the `-C` option:

```
 $ hexdump -C file.pcap
 00000000  d4 c3 b2 a1  ...
```

Or you could use xxd:

```
 $ xxd file.pcap
 00000000: d4c3 b2a1 ...
```

Comment: yes, this was it.  my code was fine but I generated the input from hexdump and didn't understand the display.  works great now!  thanks!